# SSL certificates and firewall blacklists

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, blacklist

We have a domain, erbaharlab.com, which we have bought for our research group.

[www.erbaharlab.com](http://www.erbaharlab.com) contains our research group website, nanospacejm2.erbaharlab.com contains a conference website and there might be other conference subdomains in the future, cdn.erbaharlab.com contains assets and uploads which we have created after Cloudflare migration with Cloudflare Pages. erbaharlab.com redirects to [www.erbaharlab.com](http://www.erbaharlab.com).

We have been dealing with firewall blacklists recently. We have moved our domain's NS records to Cloudflare's free plan and are making the necessary implementations.

Our current SSL certificates can be viewed from crt.sh [https://crt.sh/?q=erbaharlab.com&dir=^&sort=1&group=none](https://crt.sh/?q=erbaharlab.com&dir=%5E&sort=1&group=none). In the implementation, the certificate with the common name erbaharlab.com which ends on 2024-05-09 is active for [www.erbaharlab.com](http://www.erbaharlab.com) and nanospacejm2.erbaharlab.com. The certificate with the common name cdn.erbaharlab.com is active on cdn.erbaharlab.com.

The CAA records for the domain are automatically created by Cloudflare and cover all registered SSL certificates.

nanospacejm2.erbaharlab.com is much more important for us right now since we have to receive registration for the conference. People with some firewalls have trouble accessing the website.

Today, we were trying to reach nanospacejm2.erbaharlab.com in an institution which uses Sophos as a firewall but it was blacklisted. And we realised that when one tries to reach nanospacejm2.erbaharlab.com it is blocked. But, if one tries to reach [www.erbaharlab.com](http://www.erbaharlab.com) first and then tries to reach nanospacejm2.erbaharlab.com there is no problem with reaching the website. The expected behaviour is being unable to reach the blacklisted subdomain.

Is there any wrong configuration with the SSL certificates, which might cause the firewall blacklisting? If there is nothing wrong with the SSL certificates, how to understand there is nothing wrong?

Comment: According to https://www.virustotal.com/ three vendors report phishing for this site. The reason for this is unknown but maybe you've send out bulk mails with this link which were marked as phishing by the recipients. As for why it does not block if you first visit the www - site: the firewall might not be able to observe that you visit the acclaimed phishing site since it is inside the same TLS tunnel, due to the connection coalescing feature of HTTP/2.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you. We didn't configure the domain for any mail server, and we don't send any e-mail with this domain. Also, I have configured the DNS records in Cloudflare during the migration in a way not accepting any e-mails from this domain. But the e-mail content contains the link when we send e-mails to our e-mail list (e-mail group) about the conference. Might the link in the content cause blacklisting?

Comment: If the mail you send out was considered phishing (by a recipient or in some automatic way) then the link in the mail might be treated as dangerous. But this is just speculation, it might also have been that your site was temporarily compromised (or is still compromised) and did actually serve phishing content (at least for some users). This is often done with some deep linking, i.e. impossible to observe when just visiting the site the "normal" way.

Comment: Test your site with ssllabs.com if you suspect ssl issues. For the firewall blacklist i think you need to reach out to the engineer who manages the firewall to check why it's blacklisted, because your ssl looks good according to ssllabs.com, because without knowing the blacklist we can't say anything about that

Comment: You had no MX records set whatsoever, is that correct?

Comment: Does the domain have a negative history from its previous owners?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the SSL. There also appear to be no record of previous owners for that domain. I usually see this with Email Security systems, but it is possible that the administrators for that system is utilizing domain age (often <90d) for a blocking/reputation criteria, as it helps to reduce new domains getting created and immediately creating spam/phish.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.

SirMuffington Yes, we have no MX records. I have also set DMARC, DKIM, and SPF records after Cloudflare migration to prevent e-mail spoofing. No server can accept any e-mail from this domain now. Also, there are no previous owners.

@signus The blacklisting didn't start immediately, it started on 01 February 2024. Approximately two months later of the creation of the domain. Is this related?

Comment: It is hard to say because the information needed is under the umbrella of a few organizations and their web proxy/firewall implementations. It can even be observation of any of the included links on your site that triggered behavioral patterns or old blacklist entries (although I have been unable to find any for your domain or any of the embedded domains you link to on your registration site). When was the first deploy of the new site made (first archive available shows changes Feb 6th).

Comment: @signus It was probably 2023-12-07 for the lab website and 2023-12-21 for the conference website. But we made the lab website private on the same day and there was only a Google login page since it is hosted on Blogger. We made the lab website public again on 2023-12-15. Both are hosted on Blogger. We have used the Cloudflare free plan since 2024-02-09 for both.